# How to change speed for animation between two pictures? [pixedelic camera jquery plugin]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the speed between two pictures in my page:

```
<head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monda' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
        <link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/camera.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
               jQuery(function(){
                jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
                    height: '500px',
                    pagination: false,

                });
            });

    </head>
    <body>
<div class="slider">    
                <div class="wrap">           
                    <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">                                             
                        <div data-src="images/slider3.jpg">  </div> 
                        <div data-src="images/slider2.jpg">  </div>
                        <div data-src="images/slider1.jpg">  </div>
                        <div data-src="images/slider2.jpg">  </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="clear"> </div>                         
            </div>      </body>
</html>
```

How can I manage to change the speed? i want to increase the speed :p
THANKS

Comment: Try to modify the easing jquery easing file. I'll assume that contains the JavaScript animation settings for that plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "1200" in your code is on an event against '.scroll' which doesn't even exist in your code and scrolls the *entire page*, so won't have any effect.

Assuming the camera plugin is this (www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera) [confirmed in the comments] then you should change this code:

```
            jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
                height: '500px',
                pagination: false,
            });
```

to

```
            jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
                height: '500px',
                pagination: false,
                transPeriod: 200,
                time: 200
            });
```

where 200 is the "length of the sliding effect in milliseconds" or "milliseconds between the end of the sliding effect and the start of the [next] one"

as per the usage documentation here: http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/

Comment: Yes - that uses the pixedelic plugin - so try the change I suggested

Comment: Try with 'time' option as well/instead - I've updated answer to show where to put it.